# how to make Title beside Logo as a link to home page using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material UI, want to make title (beside Logo) as a link to Home page. I have tried to merge in both image and title in routing but it is appearing down. Didn't have any idea how to place it.
Can any one help me in this query?

When i click on `Hello World` it should redirect to home page and the hello World must be beside to Logo only.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix for your code is adding `display: inline` to your `Typography` element rendered as `<h2>`. `<h2>` is displayed as a `block` which usually starts in a new line.

```
<RouterLink to="/">
  <img
    alt="Logo"
    src="/images/logos/logo--white.svg"
  />
  <Typography variant="h5" component="h2" style={{display: 'inline'}}>
    Hello World
  </Typography>
</RouterLink>
```

Comment: It is coming Below. Its not coming in a side way and moreover line is appearing below the Hello World

Comment: You need to share a working example to help you more. But it seems like a CSS issue.